# Merge 2 Blender files with different scales loses animation

Tags: animation, transforms

I'm trying to merge 2 files, one that I made and another one with an animation. The problem is that they have different object scales so when I resize the objects, the animation doesn't work with the new size and reverts the objects back to their original size when I play it.

Comment: It’s very vague what you’re talking about. Are you saying the animated armature is in the second file and the mesh object the armature is meant to go to is in the first one? Why did you do that to yourself? Either way, it sounds like the scale has been keyframed on the animated object. You’ll need to change or delete the scale keyframes. If you want to change them, I recommend doing it in the graph editor.